# spring MVC HTTP Status 404

Tags: java, eclipse, spring-mvc, http-status-code-404

I followed [this tutorial](http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/creating-a-spring-mvc-project-using-maven-and-eclipse-in-one-minute) to make a simple MVC project, and I added one more controller and view. But now, whichever link out of following I use, I always get this error in chrome:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /spring-MVC

type Status report

message /spring-MVC

description The requested resource is not available.

Apache Tomcat/8.0.30
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.4" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>spring-MVC</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
        <param-value>
            org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
        </param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextClass</param-name>
            <param-value>
                org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext
            </param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>spring_maven.spring_MVC</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>SpringDispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

MvcConfiguration.java:

```
package spring_maven.spring_MVC.config;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.ResourceHandlerRegistry;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages="spring_maven.spring_MVC")
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

    @Bean
    public ViewResolver getViewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/views/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }


}
```

HomeController.java:

```
package spring_maven.spring_MVC.controller;

import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class HomeController {


    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public ModelAndView ejub(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException{
        return new ModelAndView("home.jsp");
    }
}
```

PlacesController.java:

```
package spring_maven.spring_MVC.controller;


import java.io.IOException;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
public class PlacesController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/getAllPlaces")
    public ModelAndView getAllPlaces() throws IOException{
        return new ModelAndView("getAllPlaces.jsp");
    }
}
```

home.jsp:

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Home</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>Hello World!</h1>
        <p>This is the homepage!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

getAllPlaces.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>getAllPlaces</title>
</head>
<body>
eeeee
</body>
</html>
```

and the structure of files in eclipse:

[image]

So as far as I see, these links should work, but they produce the mentioned errors:

http://localhost:8080/spring-MVC
http://localhost:8080/spring-MVC/getAllPlaces
http://localhost:8080/spring-MVC/home

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Your controller returns home.jsp for / so to get home url should look like http://localhost:8080/spring-MVC/

> ends with / , not /home

And I guess you don't need to use .jsp in controller return statement:

```
return new ModelAndView("home");
```

View resolver will do the rest

Comment: Here is a very good explanation of how spring mvc app works , maybe it can help you http://www.tutorialspoint.com/spring/spring_web_mvc_framework.htm

Comment: No errors in server log.. Just info about the server being started. 
The thing is, I followed the tutorial mentioned above this morning, and I got the "hello world" running, but when I do it now, from the scratch, it does not work, I get that weird error. Thanks on the link, I'll check it out..

Comment: A good idea to start will be debugging your code. Run tomcat in debug mode, put breakpoint in your home controller which catches / request , in your browser try to open home page of your app and check if your controller works, if not - some configs are wrong, if yes - spring works fine it sends your request to the correct controller which can't return view for some reason, maybe the page was placed in wrong folder.

Answer (score 0):

Error occured because of two things:
1. I forgot to drag the project into the Tomcat server which was running.
2. I forgot to restart the server.

When I did these two thing, suddenly it started working.. :)